# plt.show() doesn't show image

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib

I can't find why this plt.show() is not working. I'm using the code given in Tensorflow:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html

I found solutions saying that I should use plt.show(block=false) and add plt.pause(5) but it didn't work. Please help.

After running the code I get:
Running inference for image... Done, but it doesn't show any image.

```
    # All outputs are batches tensors.
    # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
    # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
    print('Done')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Same here, using the same example from Tensorflow v2
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#set-env

Comment: Please put the Python version, the path to the Tensorflow Object Detection API and the OS that you are using here.